# Apache Rewrite Query string problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Apache mod_rewrite:

How to rewite `/?u=http://www.google.com` to `/u/index.php?u=http://hk.yahoo.com`

Comment: Do you mean to rewrite `/?u=http://www.google.com` to `/u/index.php?u=http://www.google.com`?

Comment: Please move your answer out of your question into the answer box (you can answer your own question), then mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.(php|html)$ u/index.php?u=%1 [L]
```